# How to use a range of cells in a WHERE clause QUERY in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

[image]

If I want to select all data given a Date value (H1) how can I use a range in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant. if you want to go this route you need to flip it query it and again flip it:

```
={A1:A, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F), "where Col1 = "&H1))}
```

hard to tell what cell formating you use so if above wont work try:

```
={A1:A, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F), "where Col1 = '"&H1&"'"))}
```

or:

```
={A1:A, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:F), 
 "where Col1 date = '"&TEXT(H1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))}
```

but its easier with `FILTER`:

```
={A1:A, FILTER(B:F, B1:F1=H1)}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much :)